# Return a not null value when it return null in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wlmember.fn_string_to_row(p_str character varying)
 RETURNS SETOF text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
declare
    v_str TEXT[];
  BEGIN
    /* Check to see the number of occurences of the comma */
         v_str := string_to_array($1, ',');
    FOR i IN coalesce(array_lower(v_str, 1),1) .. coalesce(array_upper(v_str, 1),1) LOOP
      RETURN NEXT v_str[i];
    END LOOP;
        RETURN;
   END;
$function$;
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: If you want to turn a comma separated string into rows, just use `unnest(string_to_array(..., ','))` or `regexp_split_to_table()`

Comment: `COALESCE()` is used to turn NULLs into to other values of your choice.

Comment: when i pass empty string like this select wlmember.fn_string_to_row(''); it gives null value but i want any not null value like space anything ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some sample input data and the output you expect from that input. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)